# How to have global menus in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm an android newbie so forgive me if this is a noobish question.
I'm trying to have some menu which is located on top of the screen and I want it to be in every single activity inside my application.
Now my question is how can achieve this goal? Should I create an XML an include it every where or should I have a base activity and host my other activities inside that?

**UPDATE:** Look at the screenshot below, I want exactly the same. If you notice you see 2 sets of buttons one on top and the other on the bottom. The middle screen is scrollable.
[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: do you want a contextMenu? http://saigeethamn.blogspot.de/2011/05/context-menu-android-developer-tutorial.html

Comment: No, not really a context menu. I've updated the question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create the bottom and top toolbars as separate layout xml files and inclue them in the activities I need them. I also create a base activity which can handle both toolbars. You can put the top toolbar to actionbar programmatically, if it's available.

Comment: Yup, look at LayoutInflater. You'll need to setup the clicks etc... in each Activity but you can isolate that in an utility class and pass it a pointer to the current activity.

Comment: Yes, since the `Action Bars` are way to advanced for me I decided I'm gonna do the same. But the problem as you mentioned is the event listeners should be implemented in every activity. @Torp I didn't get how you said we could use a utility class. Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: What is the problem with creating a base Activity class, which is then extended instead of the Activity? Also, you could create a class which implements all of your listeners and just set it as the listener for your clicks, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In `Android` something like top menu not exists. Quoted from [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)

> There is no "top bar menu" in Android, assuming you are referring to
>   something like the bar at the top of an Windows window or the OS X
>   screen. You are welcome to create something of your own, but there is
>   no built-in platform support for such a concept.
>
> Spend some time with existing Android applications, and you will find
>   few (if any) that implement a "fixed visible menu on top". If you find
>   one that does, post some screenshots of it in action and perhaps we
>   can make some suggestions on how to implement it.

So after update you need to know something about implement actionBar.
So have look at these links

[actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) , [johannilsson / android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) , [cyrilmottier / GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)

And for adding `Buttons` to bottom, you should use `<RelativeLayout>` , add margin to `Buttons`

Buttons on bottom you can set similar like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3B3B3B"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Second"
            />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Second"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Second" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Second" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you check the screenshot please?

Comment: Yes, I think the term `Menu` doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know anything such as `Action Bar` exists.